# Why does TypeScript throw an error in an if statement checking an Union Type as if it's just a Literal Type?

Tags: typescript

Take the following TypeScript code:

```
const a: 0 | 1 = 1

if (a === 0) {
    console.log('a is 0')
}
```

The `if` statement will generate the following error:

`This condition will always return 'false' since the types '1' and '0' have no overlap.`

(you can play around in in the TypeScript Playground with this example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhgBhgHxgRhgXiwKHwEsAzGACjlxz2QEoYBvfGVmUSEAGwFMA6LiADm5AORUiEFKLr4AvkA)

My question is why does this throw an error? If you hover over the type of `a` it is correctly typed as `const a: 0 | 1`. If the compiler is so sure `a`'s type is always `1`, why doesn't it type it as `const a: 1`?

NB: If you change the code to...

```
const a = 1 as 0 | 1

if (a === 0) {
    console.log('a is 0')
}
```

...the error will go away. But it seems silly to revert to casting to fix this.

Comment: The compiler is sure of it because theres no reason for it to believe that `a` is not `1`. You're right though, if it's a `const` it should know that `a` can only be `1`, but if for example it's declared as `let` there is a chance that you could reassign it elsewhere. However, if you don't actually do that, it will throw the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" here is that Typescript is smart enough to understand that `const` can't be reassigned. This means that

```
const a: 0 | 1 = 1;
```

is the same for Typescript as doing

```
const a: 1 = 1;
```

Even though the type indicates there is a range of possible values, `const` assignment limits the type to the only possible value.
You can see this in action when you hover `a` in the conditional in the playground snippet you linked to: the type of `a` in the if statement is `1`.

When you cast the type after the fact, you're manually overriding this constraint.

You can see the same operation in action when your variable declaration is `let` but no assignment is made:

```
let a: 0 | 1 = 1;

// Same error as before, type of `a` is `1`
if (a === 0) {
    console.log('a is 0');
}
```

If there's an assignment to the variable though, the type can't be constrained (because that would be the equivalent of the halting problem), and you'll have no error.

```
let a: 0 | 1 = 1;

if (some external condition) {
    a = 0;
}

// No error, type of `a` is `0 | 1`
if (a === 0) {
    console.log('a is 0')
}
```

Comment: `const` is not the culprit, this also works with `let`. The reason why typescript thinks it can only be `1` is that theres simply no reassignment happening inside of the block.

Comment: @MikeS. Caught be just before I expanded my answer, but thank you for your input.